# SAM build in container with environment variables

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

Is there a way to pass environment variables to the container doing the build in:

```
sam build --use-container
```

In the sam build [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-build.html), in parameters related to Docker, there is only `--docker-network` and `--skip-pull-image`

#### Use case:

I am using private PyPI repository, and I need to pass credentials as environment variables.

#### Workaround:

A workaround is:

- Pull the docker image used by sam, e.g. `lambci/lambda:build-python3.7`
- Build a new image with same name & tag
- Run `sam build -u` with parameter `--skip-pull-image`

#### Update 1:

Created a feature request in SAM repo: https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/2144

#### Update 2:

New parameters were released: `--container-env-var` and `--container-env-var-file` in [v1.20.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/releases/tag/v1.20.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from release [v1.20.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/releases/tag/v1.20.0) (2021-03-04) you can pass environment variables to the container, either from the command line:

```sh
sam build --use-container \
    --container-env-var Function1.GITHUB_TOKEN=<token1> \
    --container-env-var GLOBAL_ENV_VAR=<global-token>
```

or from a file:

```sh
sam build --use-container --container-env-var-file <env-file.json>
```

Ref: [sam build](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-build.html) documentation

Comment: Hey @forzagreen, do you know how to use the --container-env-var in the rest of the code ? 
Where can I reference them ? from the docs it seems that it's a good way to pass a github token, still can't figure out how to use it.

Comment: @RoyAssis, what do you mean by "the rest of the code" ? `template.yaml` ? do you want to use environment variables at build or at deploy ?

Comment: I want to use it at build

Comment: where ? in template.yaml ? in Dockerfile ?

Comment: I want to use it in the Dockerfile

Comment: In Dockerfile you add these 2 lines: `ARG YOUR_VAR` and `ENV YOUR_VAR=${YOUR_VAR}`

Comment: I tried that, seems that doesn't work when trying to pass params with --container-env-var